# How to show specific numbers of items in HTML tables from database using jQuery DataTables?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, datatables

I've used the following HTML & PHP code for table:

```
   <?php
       $query = "select * from test";
       $execute = $conn->query($query);
   ?>
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl_blood_donar_list">
       <thead>  
           <tr>
               <th>Username</th>
               <th>Contact No.</th>
               <th>State</th>
               <th>City</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
   <?php
       while($result = $execute->fetch_array())
       {
   ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $result['user_name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $result['phone_number']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $result['state']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $result['city']; ?></td>
          </tr>
   <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I've used the following code to show the database items into HTML tables using DataTables:

```
        <script>
            $('#tbl_blood_donar_list').dataTable({
                "order": [
                    [0, 'asc']
                ],
                "lengthMenu": [
                    [5, 15, 20, -1],
                    [5, 15, 20, "All"]
                ],
                "pageLength": 10,
                "columnDefs": [{ 
                    'orderable': true,
                    'targets': [0]
                }, {
                    "searchable": true,
                    "targets": [0]
                },
                {
                    'bSortable' : false,
                    'aTargets' : [3]
                }]
            });
       </script>
```

According to the above code only the first five items are shown in the page by default, but it shows the entire items which are retrieved from database. Furthermore it does not shows the pagination. Let's check the following images:

[Image: Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzFrU.png)

I need to select another option from the records select box (15, 20, or all) to show the specific number of items & also the pagination, again when I select 5 in records select box the tables is working fine. Let's check the image:

[Image: Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIVrn.png)

**The problem is:** when the page is loaded 5 is selected by default but the table shows entire items found in the database based on the query. When I select 15, or 20 or All from the select box the table shows 15, or 20 or all records, again when I select 5, it shows 5 records.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my JS code (DataTables) or HTML, PHP code? How can I fix this issue.

Comment: What version of Datatables are you running?

Comment: doesn't make sense setting menu to 5 but default length to 10

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `pageLength` to 5, not to 10 (btw, 10 is the default):

```
$('#tbl_blood_donar_list').dataTable({
    "pageLength": 5, 
    ...
});
```

`lengthMenu` only sets the menu, but the default is still 10 items per page. You need to modify the default page length using `"pageLength": n`, where `n` is the number of items you want to display by default.

Useful links:

- https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength
- https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

Change your code to (if you want 5 as default):

```
<script>
    $('#tbl_blood_donar_list').dataTable({
        "order": [[0, 'asc']],
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 15, 20, -1],[5, 15, 20, "All"]],
        "pageLength": 5,
        "columnDefs": [{ 
            'orderable': true,
            'targets': [0]
        }, {
            "searchable": true,
            "targets": [0]
        }, {
            'bSortable' : false,
            'aTargets' : [3]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Probably. Test using only the `"pageLength": 5` on your `dataTable`

Comment: No, still not working. If I use `"pageLength": 5`, a dropdown list is shown in the page with the values 10, 25, 50 & 100, but all the data from database is shown.